# Does the Sublime Text 2 Build System accept input, if does not are there any workarounds?

Tags: input, cygwin, sublimetext2, sublimetext

**Objective**

Set up a Sublime Text 2 Build System that allows to compile and run C programs. I have been able to painfully get to this point, but now I have some things that I cannot figure out so my two mains questions:

1) I hit ctrl+b (it compiles successfully), then ctrl+shift+b and the script runs by it doesn't take any input? Is this normal?

2) If Sublime Build Systems do not take input, there must be some workarounds. For example I press ctrl+b Sublime Text 2 compiles the file but when I press ctrl+shift+b, Sublime launches cygwin, navigates to my current directory, then does ./filename.c. Is this possible? [Here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#options) it says Sublime Text 2 suppresses GUIs but it is possible to make to make Sublime open MATLAB with the build system, so maybe I can do the same thing with Cygwin?

```
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc", "-std=c89", "-pedantic", "-Wall", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    // "cmd" : ["bash ${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "path" : "C:/cygwin64/bin/",
    "shell":true,
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    //"working_dir" : "$file_path"
    "variants": [
        {
          "cmd" : ["${file_base_name}.exe"],
          "name": "Run"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for looking.

**EDIT**

I am trying to give input to my executable when it runs. For example my script prompts the user to enter in a number, letter, string, etc using scanf or getchar(), and then store the result in a variable that I will use later on. Right now when I press ctrl+shift+B in Sublime Text it runs but skips all the input stuff.

That is my current build system. If it not possible to use Sublime Text 2 to enter in input, then i want to modify it to Sublime launches cygwin, navigate to my current directory, then do ./filename.c.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you trying to give input to your executable when it runs? Or are you somehow trying to dynamically communicate with the build system while it's running/compiling? And what are you trying to do with your second question? Do you want `${file_base_name}.exe` to run under Cygwin? The docs notwithstanding, it is possible to launch GUIs under Windows, you just need to tweak your build system. Please [edit] your question to describe ***exactly*** what you are trying to do, and what your current issues are that are preventing you from doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone over at the sublimetext channel on the freenode irc helped me out and answered my questions (shoutout to them on stackoverflow [@Zren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947742/zren)). Here is the final working script:

**Description**

- Ctrl+b compiles the "C" script using Cygwin (with the flags -std=c89, -pedantic, -Wall)
- If there are any errors you can see them underneath your code straight in the Sublime integrated window
- Press f4 and shift-f4 to navigate through them in Sublime Text
- If there are no errors it says finished in so and so seconds
- Ctrl+shift+b runs the script, it opens command prompt in a new window and runs the script there, and you can give input (Yay! :))

**Code**

```
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc", "-std=c89", "-pedantic", "-Wall", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "path" : "C:/cygwin64/bin/",
    "shell":true,
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "variants": [
        {
          "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
          "name": "Run",
          "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**In the future**

Hopefully Google can lead people here since Sublime Text 2 documentation is very poor, and I don't want anybody else to struggle with this simple yet time consuming problem.

Tags: Sublime Text 2, gcc, cygwin, build, c, input, Windows

Comment: How is Cygwin opening if you're running `cmd` (which is Windows' `cmd.exe`)?

Comment: @MattDMo Oh good catch. Yeah it only compiles with Cygwin, runs using command prompt.